# Не загружается файловая система в Twig

Tags: php, twig

Да автозагрузчик установлен.

вот код атолоадера:

```
`require_once 'vendor/autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

spl_autoload_register("gbStandardAutoload");


  function gbStandardAutoload($className)
  {
    $dirs = [
      'composer',
      'controller',
      'model',
      'app/core'
    ];
    $found = false;
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
      $fileName = __DIR__ . '/'. $dir . '/' . $className . '.class.php';
      if (is_file($fileName)) {

        require_once($fileName);
        $found = true;
      }
    }
    //$obj = new A;

    if (!$found) {
      throw new Exception('Unable to load ' . $className);
    }
    return true;
}`
```

структура папок:

```
в корне: app/core
         cofiguration (где лежит config.defaul.php)
         templates
         файл autoload.php
```

`$config['path_templates'] = $config['path_root'] . '/../templates';
$config['path_root' = это переменная __DIR__`

Вот часть кода из класса App который находится в app/core:

```
`if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
           $controllerName = ucfirst($_GET['page']) . 'Controller'; //IndexController
           $methodName = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'index';
           $controller = new $controllerName(); //new

           $data = [
             'content_data' => $controller->$methodName($_GET['id']),
             'title' => $controller->title,
           ];
           if (!isset($_GET['a'])) {
             $view = $controller->view . '/' . $methodName . '.html.twig'; //index/index.html
             $temp = Config::get('path_templates');
             echo ($temp);
             $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(Config::get('path_templates'));
             $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

             try {
               $template = $twig->load($view);
             } catch (LoaderError $e) {
               echo ($e->getMessage());
             } catch (RuntimeError $e) {
               ($e->getMessage());
             } catch (SyntaxError $e) {
               ($e->getMessage());
             }
             echo $template->render($data);
           } else {
             echo json_encode($data);`
```

вот путь который выводится

```
E:\OSPanel\domains\duellist.dev\configuration/../templates
```

вот ошибка

> ArrayUnable to load Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader

что за Array понять не могу может к этой ошибке относится, может и нет, хотя везде поотключал вывод на экран

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Подключен ли у вас автолоадер, и правильный ли путь к папке templates? Приведите структуру проекта

Comment: Необходимы данные добавил выше изменил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `\Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader` должен подключать автозагрузчик вендора ( https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/3.x/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php ), а подключает атозагрузчик ядра. Twig установлен? В структуре папок нету инфы не о папке vendor, не о папке vendor/twig. 
Выполните `composer update` на всякий случай.

Comment: update сделал, twig 3, в коде автозагрузчика первые две строки где подключается и регистрируется Twig_autoloader, и про какое ядро имеешь ввиду? Структура Vendora как и везде там все ставится автоматом, твиг устанавливал композером

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в неправильном подключении автозагрузчика, я в стартовом файле прописал
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
и прописал spl_autoload_register("gbStandardAutoload"); соответственно саму функцию  gbStandardAutoload также перенёс в стартовый файл, и удалил свой автолодер классов.